# Mean of numbers from a sample function

Tags: r

So i wrote a code where basically a die is rolled a bunch of times.
So I have to modify this code now so that instead of taking the sum of every 1 it rolls, It takes the mean or average number rolled :

```
count_ones <- function(k) {
  ones <- sum(sample(1:6, k, TRUE) == 1)
  return(ones/k)
}
```

i'm not sure how to get the mean of a sample function if that makes sense

Comment: `mean(sample(1:6, k, TRUE))` will do the job for you.

Comment: yeah that's what i thought but it wasn't working

Comment: just try `mean(sample(1:6, 4, TRUE))` and you will get the answer. You dont need to write a function even.